# Why EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init does not work with the same CTX that RSA keys are generated from?

Tags: c, openssl

I have a class that manages RSA keys. In one of its interfaces it generates a pair of key and at the same time it initializes the CTX to be used for the decryption using the private key. The strange thing (or at least seems to be strange to me) that I am facing there is that after generating the keys I have to free the old CTX, create a new one and initialize it with the already generated key pair so that decryption works. Trial to call EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init with old (initial) CTX will result in segmentation fault. Could anyone please verify if this is the correct way of initialization of the CTX for the decryption and if no how such initialization should be done with original CTX. (RAII concept is taken care of in the context of the class not focus of this question)

```
  bool generateKeyPair() override
  {
    if (_keypair)
    {
      EVP_PKEY_free(_keypair);
      _keypair = nullptr;
    }

    if (!_ctx)
    {
      _ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_id(EVP_PKEY_RSA, nullptr);
      if (!_ctx)
      {
        logError("Failed to create EVP_PKEY_CTX.");
        return false;
      }
      logDebug("ctx created successfully.");
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen_init(_ctx) <= 0)
    {
      logError("Failed to initialize EVP_PKEY_CTX.");
      return false;
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_CTX_set_rsa_keygen_bits(_ctx, 2048) <= 0)
    {
      logError("Failed to set RSA key size.");
      return false;
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_keygen(_ctx, &_keypair) <= 0)
    {
      logError("Failed to generate RSA key pair.");
      return false;
    }
    // here I need to free the context and cerate a new one with the
    // already created keys so that decryption works correcty
    if (_ctx)
    {
      EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(_ctx);
      _ctx = nullptr;
    }

    _ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new(_keypair, NULL);

    // Initialize the ctx to be able to do decryption
    if (EVP_PKEY_decrypt_init(_ctx) <= 0)
    {
      logError("Failed to initialize RSA decryption.\n");
      EVP_PKEY_free(_keypair);
      _keypair = nullptr;
      EVP_PKEY_CTX_free(_ctx);
      _ctx = nullptr;
      return false;
    }

    return true;
  }
```

Comment: Did you mean to tag this c++ instead of c?

Comment: No actually it is c API related question has nothing to do with c++

Comment: What is `override`?

Comment: It is part of a bigger structure and here is only one interface of the class. Focus of the question is how to correctly interact with openssl C API.

Comment: My guess is override is a C++ keyword.  Anyways, I will butt out, but I think it's confusing as is.